# Get display ratio for crop-pick intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using the following code to pick a cropped image from the user's gallery that matches the screen's display width/height (to be able to set it as a background for my fullscreen Activity):

```
    int PHOTO_WIDTH = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int PHOTO_HEIGHT = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("outputX", PHOTO_WIDTH);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", PHOTO_HEIGHT);
```

This works on some devices, but not on others (even if they have the same xhpdi-density).

How can I get the current screen ratio (incl. the status bar, excl. the soft-key-button row) and set it to the PICK-intent?

Comment: Android does not have a crop `Intent`: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html

Comment: I'm using a try/catch (ActivityNotFoundException e), the stock and Samsung gallery app respond to this, I haven't tried other devices. It's a minor part of my app, so I'd rather not include a 3MB library because of this.

Comment: You are welcome to provide evidence that any of those linked-to libraries would add 3MB to your app.

Comment: All of the libraries require an "ASPECT_X"/"ASPECT_Y" or "SIZE_X"/"SIZE_Y" parameter, so I'm usure as to how your comment addresses my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply using the display width/height as values for the `aspect_x` and `aspect_y` parameters:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int aspect_x = display.getWidth();
int aspect_y = display.getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use values provided by [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html):

> public int    screenHeightDp  The current height of the available screen
> space, in dp units, corresponding to screen height resource qualifier.
>
> public int    screenWidthDp   The current width of the available screen
> space, in dp units, corresponding to screen width resource qualifier.

Because you are interested in the ratio, the unit does not matter (dp and not px). You can the the configuration like that:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
```